# .git commit ignoring directories that used to contain a .git

Tags: git, github

In my index.html I have some iframes that are linked to websites stored in my project. It works fine on my local files, but when I push it to github and open the actual webpage - liviarett.com - I get error 404.

Checking my github repo, I noticed that the websites' directories are showing as a double folder icon, and I read online that that might be because they contained .git files.

So I deleted the .gits and tried committing everything again, but it says there is nothing to commit - I tried changing something else in those folders, but it seems that my .git is ignoring them for some reason.
Any thoughts? my repo is https://github.com/liviarett/liviarett.github.io

Comment: I am not sure what is .gits and where did you read that it is inside one of your folder ?

Comment: https://github.com/liviarett/liviarett.github.io/commit/0fe275f076ca0eb0541bc6a4d91e8eef0a0b25c7#diff-54e1d44609e3abed11f6e1eb6ae54988 You added a submodule which is pointing to a location that is unreachable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that they each had a .git from when I was building the websites. All I did was commit these files. How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

After Eyorther mentioned that I created a submodule, I found the answer here: https://humansky.com/2011/12/accidentally-adding-a-git-submodule/

Once the .git file is deleted from your directory:

Here is what you need to do in order to remove the submodule and add as a subfolder:

git rm --cached subfolder
git add subfolder
git commit -m "Enter message here"
git push